# How to know if the function is convex

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, contest-math, education

How I can know if this function is a convex and why ?
My understanding is the exp is convex and if we add positive number to a convex we return a convex
then the log for convex sometimes return convex sometime
log (1 + exp(wT xi)) for w ∈ Rd

Comment: The example function in your question is convex, but showing this is rather challenging.  Are you aware of the convex function log_sum_exp?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.